# MySQL to calculate a value against price at the nearest date in another table

Tags: mysql, date, select, join

I have 2 tables where I want to calculate a value across. One table provides daily price data (prices) which is historic while the second contains annual data (volumes) which contains both historic and projected data. So far, I can join the two tables so that I can calculate the historic annual value by the price at the corresponding date in the daily one, but not for the future annual values where I would like to calculate against the last daily price in the prices table.

Current table structure

```
Table 1: Prices   (3 fields: date,code,price)
Table 2: Volumes  (3 fields: date,code,units)
```

Current query

```
SELECT v.date,p.price,v.units,CONCAT(p.price*v.units) AS Value
FROM Prices p,Volumes v
WHERE p.code = v.code AND p.date = v.date
AND v.code = 'X' AND (v.date BETWEEN '2012-12-31' AND '2016-12-31')
GROUP BY v.date
ORDER BY v.date
LIMIT 5;
```

results in 2012-2013 data rather than 2012-2016:

```
date   2012-12-31   2013-12-31 
price    50            58
units   100            90
Value  5000           5220
```

My annual table (Volumes) has volume estimates for years 2014,2015 and 2016 (which are not shown) and the last price in the daily table (Prices) is say 65, but the above query will only match the volumes to the corresponding date value in the daily price table rather than using the nearest last value. Can someone advise me on how best to do this please?

example of tables (note: both tables use a composite primary key around 'date' and 'code')

Volumes

```
date           code    units
2012-12-31     X        100
2012-12-31     Y         50
2013-12-31     X         90
2013-12-31     Y         45
2014-12-31     X         95
2014-12-31     Y         47
```

Prices

```
date           code    price
2013-12-31     X         50
2013-12-31     Y         25
2014-01-01     X         58
2014-01-01     Y         27
2014-01-02     X         59
2014-01-02     Y         30
-----
2014-03-31     X         48
2014-03-31     Y         26
2014-04-01     X         49
2014-04-01     Y         27
last data point
```

Comment: can you post some sample data or a sql fiddle? and i'm not completely sure what your question is.. is what you want the "Value" calculation between 2012 and 2016?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the 2 tables have date fields that are similar (eg yyyy-mm-dd) as are the code fields (eg X,Y,Z) and both of these are composite primary keys in each table. The 'units' in Volumes table and 'Price' in Prices table are integers.

Comment: i mean can you post like 5-10 rows of data from your two tables with dates between your wanted daterange?

Comment: I don't think I can input a formatted table here, but the the daily price table will have daily historic date data (eg '2013-10-15',2013-10-16' etc) while the volume annual table, the date data will be for the year end (eg '2013-12-31','2014-12-31','2015-12-31' etc). My above query therefore can select by the date where they match across both tables, but not for the future annual data as the daily price data contains only historic price values. What I need is to take the last available price from the daily data to use to calculate the future annual values.

Comment: example of tables added. Hopefully a little clearer

Comment: Just to clarify. I have a table of historic daily price data which is updated every day and another table of volume data which is on an annual basis, but which includes both historic and projected annual data. To calculate the historic value data I can take the above query which will select the price from the daily table to match against the historic date from the annual table. This however will not work for the future annual values where I need to take the last available price from the daily table to calculate against the projected annual volume data.

Comment: so all you want is a query to get the future values by getting the most recent price and multiply that by the future units?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query to get the future values by multiplying the future projected unit quantity with the most recent price recorded then this would be the query. see working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc596/12)

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (future_units*last_price) as projeted_value --- dont need the CONCAT for this calculation
FROM(
  SELECT 
    v.date, 
    v.units as future_units,
    (SELECT 
       price 
     FROM prices
     ORDER BY date desc --- desc for the most recent
     LIMIT 1) as last_price --- just need the first one
  FROM volumes v
  WHERE v.date > NOW() --- to make it a future date
)as t --- table needs alias
```

---

updated query per the OP request.. working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc596/36)
This one calculates the price related with the date.. once you get to future dates it calculates the last price with the future units

```
SELECT
  *,
  if(DATE(the_date) > NOW(), --- if its a future date put in last_price, else put in the current_price
    (future_units*last_price),
    (future_units*current_price))AS value
FROM(
  SELECT
    v.date AS the_date,
    v.units AS future_units,
    v.code,
    p.price AS current_price,
    (SELECT
       price
     FROM prices
     ORDER BY date DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS last_price
  FROM prices p
  LEFT JOIN volumes v ON p.code = v.code
  WHERE p.date >= v.date OR p.date < v.date
  AND DATE(v.date) BETWEEN '2012-12-31' AND '2016-12-31' -- DATE() used to cut out timestamp for accurate comparison
  GROUP BY v.date, v.code, v.units
)AS t
```

Comment: I think I need to get my head around this one as I don't immediately see where to insert the selection criteria for the code item (eg select 'code')or the date selection against the Volumes table (eg date BETWEEN '2012-12-31' AND '2016-12-31').

Comment: so if you want a future date then it would be a date that is greater than today. which is why I did `WHERE v.date > NOW()`  what this query is doing is it is getting the price at the last data point and using that price to multiply with the projected units

Comment: this is a sample with the date range between 2012 and 2016 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc596/17 --- also if you look at the INSERT INTO prices.. the last record put in there is the latest one and the price is 27 which is what you had asked for (`What I need is to take the last available price from the daily data to use to calculate the future annual values`)

Comment: OK, I see what what you've done. You are calculating the the values of each v.unit for the annual periods 2012-12-31 to 2016-12-31 from the last price from p.price (the current price). What I was after though was to value the periods 2012-12-31 to 2016-12-31 by their corresponding prices where available (eg 2012-12-31 and 2013-12-31), but use the current price for the future periods (eg 2014-12-31 to 2016-12-31). In the above example, that would mean that '2013-12-31' would price X at 50, while for '2014-12-31' the price used would by 49; the last available price for X as at '2014-04-01'

Comment: also it would be best to add ID's to this table as this is much more difficult to do without them

Comment: Ok i got it working and updated my answer with the query. let me know if that works for you

Comment: let me get back to you tomorrow on this (now almost 1am here in UK) - thx